# Use JDK11 for specific Maven submodule compilation fails

Tags: maven, java-11, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a Maven project with 3 submodules: 2 of them should be compiled with java8 and one of them with java11. My main JAVA_HOME environment variable when running maven is set to the JDK 8 installed in my machine. I want to specify to use the jdk 11 only for the specific submodule that needs it but I can't make it work.

In the POM father I have the following

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the specific subproject that needs jdk 11 I tried to setup things following this documentation http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html so I have

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <release>11</release>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <fork>true</fork>
    <executable>${JAVA_11_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

and the JAVA_11_HOME variable is set in my settings.xml (according to the doc)

When I run the compilation (either of the whole project or of the single java11 submodule) I get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile 
(default-compile) on project features-serving: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project 
features-serving: Compilation failure
```

If I run with debug and stacktrace enabled I don't get any useful information. Basically I cannot figure out what it is going wrong. Only thing I am sure is that maven is picking up correctly the JDK 11 path from my settings.xml file.

Comment: Any specific reason you don't use the JDK11 for all modules (JDK11 can also build for Java 8)?

Comment: The other submodules need to be built using Java 8. Can I do that running maven with java11?

Comment: If you set `<source>` and `<target>` to `1.8`, the project is build for Java 8, independent of the JDK (if the JDK is at least 1.8, of course).

Comment: this doesn't work either. Even if I specify jdk8 in the submodule that needs java 8 it fails because of some known compilation issues related to incompatibility of one of the deps of this module with java11

Comment: The first question I have: Why do you need to compile with JDK11 only one module? What is the issue you are trying to solve? Apart from your compile errors?

Comment: The other module uses apache spark which is not compatible with jdk11. I know I can split projects but I would like to make it work like this since the maven compiler plugin states that it is possible to use a different JVM for a certain build step

Comment: If you have a module which is not compatible with JDK11 than why are you using JDK11 ? Are those modules independent ? Or those modules combined into a single application?

Comment: They are independent sharing some common dependencies. I am aware I can split them and solve the problem. I just would like to know if I can make it work like this first. The plugin should work with my setup but it doesn't